# Remove widget in gtk.Table?

Tags: python, pygtk, removechild

I'm using gtk.Table in my python application. How can I remove a widget such a gtk.VBox, gtk.HBox or a gtk.Button that I attached in the table? I want to remove the widget in exactly position. Is there anyway to unattach a child widget from table? 
Such like:

```
table.attach(button,1,2,1,2)
table.unattach(button,1,2,1,2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table.remove(button)
```

This works in general for GTK containers, such as hboxes and vboxes, not just tables.

Comment: thanks. But i attach some buttons to table in a loop. Then i want to unattach just only 1 button, example the button at position (1,2,1,2). How can i do it ?

Comment: If you know you're going to be removing them later, the easiest way would be to just save the button variables and do as I did. If that's not possible, you can run `children = table.get_children()` and `children` will be a list of all the widgets you have in the table.

Comment: Also, since you seem to be new here, Stack Overflow etiquette is that you're supposed to upvote helpful answers and then accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not unattach.

table.remove(button,1,2,1,2) it works.

Comment: What version of Gtk allows you to remove by coordinates? This doesn't work. There is no such API that matches the above example.